# Getting the time a request spent in Phusion Passenger queue

Tags: passenger

Is there a way to get the time a request has spent in the Passenger queue before being forwarded to an application process? This would be very valuable information to decide if it makes any sense to start working on the request or if it would be better to just drop it because it is likely that the client has already timed out or because I want to reserve capacity for higher priority requests. I am aware of the passenger_max_request_queue_time setting, but at the app level I have more information about how important the request is.